# express router test with multiple handlers

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

I am testing my guard middleware, but altough everything seems to be working fine my expect statement fails.

/// auth.test.js

```
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');
const app = require('../../app');
const authMiddleware = require('./auth.middleware');

const mockRes = () => {
  const res = {};
  res.status = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
  res.sendStatus = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
  res.send = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
  return res;
};

describe('Authorization', () => {
  const guardedRouter = express.Router();

  guardedRouter.get(
    '/guardedandauthenticated',
    [authMiddleware.authenticate, authMiddleware.authorize('admin')],
    (req, res, _next) => {
      console.log('seems to be working');
      res.status(200);
      console.log('res is 200000000');
    },
  );

  let accessToken = '';
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const res = await request(app).post('/auth/login').send({
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin',
    });
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    accessToken = res.body.accessToken;
  });


  it('should allow access to authorized roles', () => {
    const response = mockRes();
    // @ts-ignore
    guardedRouter.handle(
      {
        headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
        url: '/guardedandauthenticated',
        method: 'GET',
      },
      response,
    );
    // THIS EXPECTATION IS FAILED
    expect(response.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
  });
});
```

/// auth.middleware.js

```
    module.exports.authorize = role => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.status(403).send({
        message: 'Unauthorized! No token provided!',
      });
    }
    if (req.user.role === undefined) {
      const privileges = await userService.getUserPrivileges(req.user.id);
      req.user.role = privileges.map(f => f.privilege_name);
    }
    const userRoles = req.user.role;

    const rolesToCheck = Array.isArray(role) ? role : [role];
    if (!rolesToCheck.every(r => userRoles.includes(r))) {
      return res.status(403).send({
        message: `Unauthorized! Required privileges are: ${userRoles.toString()}`,
      });
    }
    return next();
  };
};
```

/// jest outcome

```
   expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: 200

    Number of calls: 0
```

I cleaned up the code, my similar assertions are successfull, and the code seems to be working fine, either the way I setup router is incorrect, or, actually I have no clue. Console messages in the router are on the jest output, so it works fine.
Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

well it turned out to be a jest issue, you need to tell jest that you are done.

```
  it('should allow access to authorized roles', async done => {
    const res = { statusCode: 100 };
    res.status = function (code) {
      res.statusCode = code;
      return res;
    };
    // @ts-ignore
    guardedRouter.handle(
      {
        headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
        url: '/guardedandauthenticated',
        method: 'GET',
      },
      res,
    );
    setTimeout(() => {
      done();
      expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
    }, 300);
  });
```

so I added a done callback to test case, and checked value after the handler is done. This still does not look like an ideal solution. The thing is that, handle will call 3 functions, one of them is async, I could not get it to report correct without setting a timer. There should be a solution without the timer, can anyone help with that?